# The trait `Id` is not implemented for `Token`

Tags: anchor, spl-token, spl-token-program

I am trying to write a program to transfer a SPL Token but I'm having trouble when I pass the token_program account to my instruction:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeAuction<'info> {
    /// State of our auction program (up to you)
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + BoyncAuction::AUCTION_SIZE
    )]
    pub state: Account<'info, BoyncAuction>,

    /// Account which holds tokens bidded by biders
    #[account(mut)]
    pub treasury: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}
```

When I compile I get the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Token: Id` is not satisfied
  --> programs/auction/src/lib.rs:62:24
   |
62 |     pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Id` is not implemented for `Token`
   |
```

I am using code from a not so old youtube [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GHlk6vosQw) that compiled.

I am currently using `anchor-cli 0.25.0`, is something change that will not allow me to use a Token Program Account this way?

Comment: You need anchor-spl and anchor-lang as dependencies, not anchor-cli, necessarily. Also, can you restart your rust analyzer server or run cargo clean and recompile the file? Seems fine to me.

Comment: My dependencies in Cargo.toml:


[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.22.1"
anchor-spl = "0.25.0"
spl-associated-token-account = "1.0.5"

Comment: I built clean, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had been working in an existing anchor repo and the 'anchor-lang' in Cargo.toml did not corespond with what version of anchor-cli I have installed. ('0.22.0' vs '0.25.0').

That was causing tons of errors for me including the one I described above.

```
note: perhaps two different versions of crate `anchor_lang` are being used?'
```

^^ If you see this, check whatever you have installed vs what's declared unde [dependencies] in Cargo.toml.